# Is there any software (with a graphical user interface) for creating Style Layer Descriptors?

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is there any software that can easily create a Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) without using a  script?

Comment: I second that mention of QGIS and the "save as SLD" plugin - it will even allow you to publish it directly to GeoServer without having to "save" to a file first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try these:

- [Altas Styler](http://en.geopublishing.org/AtlasStyler)
- [Udig](http://udig.refractions.net/)
- [Kosmo](http://www.opengis.es/) or [OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org/)
- And [Qgis](http://qgis.org/index.php) either natively or with the help of the SLD plugin

Answer (score 3):

If you are an ArcGIS Desktop user. Have a look at GeoCat Bridge:  http://geocat.net.

If you're looking for webbased solutions, try GXP Styler: http://gxp.opengeo.org.

QGIS now has native support for SLD.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two more options:

1. You can install the [GeoExt Styler](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/styler.html) extension and use it directly to set the styles.
2. If you have ArcGIS desktop, and want to convert from your Map Documents/ layer files to sld files without any headaches, you can use [Arc2Earth](http://help.arc2earth.com/help/kb/arc2earth-desktop/export-map-symbols-to-styled-layer-descriptor-sld). They even have a free (free as in Beer) community edition, which you can use to export the sld files of layers one at a time. As someone who is far too invested in ArcGIS desktop, I can't  overstate how easy it has made my life.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tilemill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/). it allows you to export SLD (compatible with mapnik)

Answer (score 1):

Use geoserver CSS module
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/index.html
It creates SLD by it's own, there is no need to learn SLD.